# IB - Dragging items into `scrollview` without repositioing?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have unfortunately decided to make my app using the IB, which I discovered was a terrible choice, but I'm afraid I must deal with it.

So originally, I had all my fields, buttons, etc, placed on a single view, with enough space left on the bottom that on the 3.5" screens everything displays neatly.

Well was that a terrible idea. Now I need to add just a few more things to the screen, and although it works in the 4" mode, 3.5" is out of luck. "Ah ha," I thought, "All I need to do is add a `scrollview` containing everything on my screen, and for the 3.5", it will scroll instead of reposition.

Long story short, I added my `subview`, placed it as the very back object on my screen, draged all items into it... And I got a mess.

[image: What a mess]

Ain't that just dandy.

Anyways, I would like to know if there is someway to get Xcode to not reposition all these elements when I do this, or, is there another way to get all these elements to become `subviews` under this `scrollview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select all the views from the tree on the left. Then click once on the view controller's frame (the black status bar, not the objects inside the controller). Now press cntl-c to copy all of them. Now double click on the view you wish to add them to and paste them. This will retain all the view's layout locations. If they don't copy over exactly into position just hold down shift and press the arrow keys to get them into position. Dragging the views into another view reset all the position back to the center.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked fine. What I did was simply: Select everything form the tree on the left like you said. Then Cmd+x'd them, double-clicked on the scrollview in that pane, and then Cmd+v'd them. I did have to move everything over a little bit, but it was quite easy. Thanks again. You don't know how much frustration you just saved me.

Comment: We have all been there... ;-) No prob!